# How to filter by Date fields in Django-filter package?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

My model

```py
class Metric(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField()
    channel = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    os = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I am using the [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/rest_framework.html) to filter the records. Can someone help how I can filter by time range (date_from+date_to is enough). Like in query parameter user will provide `/metrics?date-gte='2021-08-17'&date-lte='2021-08-19'`

my view

```py
class MetricViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MetricSerializer
    queryset = Metric.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['country', 'channel','os']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `filterset_fields` to automatically generate the filterset specify it using `filterset_class` ([Docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/rest_framework.html#adding-a-filterset-with-filterset-class)) and use the [`DateFromToRangeFilter` [django-filter docs]](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html#datefromtorangefilter) to allow filtering by a range for dates:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters


class MetricFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    date = filters.DateFromToRangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = Metric
        fields = ['country', 'channel', 'os', 'date']


class MetricViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MetricSerializer
    queryset = Metric.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = MetricFilter
```

You can provide query parameters like `/metrics?date_after=2021-08-17&date_before=2021-08-19`.

Comment: Thanks this works like charm. Can you please take a look at this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68895105/how-to-serialize-the-aggregated-record-in-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 0):

I think `Metric.objects.filter(date__range('2021-08-17', '2021-08-19'))` can do the job? Maybe you need turn the date string into date object first.

For your reference: [Range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#range)