# How to serialize the Grouped record in Django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

model

```py
class Metric(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField()
    channel = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    os = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    impressions = models.IntegerField()
    clicks = models.IntegerField()    

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.date, self.channel)
```

My view

```py
class MetricViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = MetricSerializer
    queryset = Metric.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = MetricFilter
```

My serializer

```py
class MetricSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Metric
        fields = '__all__'
```

**I need to group by one or more columns: date, channel, country, operating system** and serialize it. Can someone help me with how I can do it?

```
select channel, country, sum(impressions) as impressions, sum(clicks) as clicks from sample dataset where date < '2017-06-01' group by channel, country order by clicks desc;
     channel      | country | impressions | clicks 
------------------+---------+-------------+--------
 adcolony         | US      |      532608 |  13089
 apple_search_ads | US      |      369993 |  11457
 vungle           | GB      |      266470 |   9430
 vungle           | US      |      266976 |   7937
```

Comment: Would be great to see an example of the aggregated response you expect to have for a better understanding. 
`ModelViewSet` provides certain actions around `Metric` model and will assume input/output to have schema of `MetricSerializer`. You might need to use custom extra actions https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing.

Comment: @rootart - I have added it in the questions

Answer (score 0):

you should define a new field in serializer:

```
class MetricSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    annotated_field = serializers.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = Metric
        fields = [ 'annotated_field', 'other fields']
```

and change the query set on view or where you want to serialize data:

```
class MetricViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    ...
    queryset = Metric.objects.annotate(annotated_field=...)
    ...
```